# nested subscription in angular 4 rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

i open a modal and subscribe to an event in modal, 
    then when the subscription is called I call another method  (method 2), 
    method 2 use a service and I subscribe to that service, but subscription never runs

```
method1(selectedAudits) {
    this.bsModalref = this.bsModalService.show(SomeAngularComponent);
    this.bsModalref.content.someEventInSomeAngularComponent.subscribe(data => {
        //the subscription works 
        console.log('subscription works and messaged is logged to console')
            //methode 2 is successfully called 
        this.method2(data);
    });
}

method2(data) {
    //the service is called and data is send to server 
    this.someService.sendDataToServer(data).subscribe(result => {
        //??????????????????
        //why the subscrion doent work here ?
        console.log('this is second subscribtion that is never logged to console ')
    })
}
```

Comment: try to call `method2(data)` directly

Comment: it has to be indirectly

Comment: @Arash does your service call is working ?? are you sure `http` req has been fulfilled successfully ? May be check your network panel or console  to check if there is any error or not

Comment: yes it works , i have already checked it .